# BS4: issues finding href of 2 tags

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm having problems getting soup to return all links that are both bold and have a URL. Right now it's only returning the 1st one on the page.

Here is part of the source:

```
<div class="section_wrapper" id="all_players_">
<div class="section_heading">
  <span class="section_anchor" id="players__link" data-label="925 Players"></span>
    <h2>925 Players</h2>    <div class="section_heading_text">
      <ul> <li><strong>Bold</strong> indicates active player and + indicates a Hall of Famer.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>      
</div>    <div class="section_content" id="div_players_">
<p><a href="/players/d/d'acqjo01.shtml">John D'Acquisto</a>  (1973-1982)</p>
<p><a href="/players/d/d'amije01.shtml">Jeff D'Amico</a>  (1996-2004)</p>
<p><a href="/players/d/d'amije02.shtml">Jeff D'Amico</a>  (2000-2000)</p>
<p><a href="/players/d/dantoja01.shtml">Jamie D'Antona</a>  (2008-2008)</p>
<p><a href="/players/d/dorseje02.shtml">Jerry D'Arcy</a>  (1911-1911)</p>
<p><b><a href="/players/d/darnach01.shtml">Chase d'Arnaud</a>  (2011-2016)</b></p>
<p><b><a href="/players/d/darnatr01.shtml">Travis d'Arnaud</a>  (2013-2016)</b></p>
<p><a href="/players/d/daalom01.shtml">Omar Daal</a>  (1993-2003)</p>
<p><a href="/players/d/dadepa01.shtml">Paul Dade</a>  (1975-1980)</p>
<p><a href="/players/d/dagenjo01.shtml">John Dagenhard</a>  (1943-1943)</p>
<p><a href="/players/d/daglipe01.shtml">Pete Daglia</a>  (1932-1932)</p>
<p><a href="/players/d/dagrean01.shtml">Angelo Dagres</a>  (1955-1955)</p>
<p><b><a href="/players/d/dahlda01.shtml">David Dahl</a>  (2016-2016)</b></p>
<p><a href="/players/d/dahlja01.shtml">Jay Dahl</a>  (1963-1963)</p>
<p><a href="/players/d/dahlebi01.shtml">Bill Dahlen</a>  (1891-1911)</p>
<p><a href="/players/d/dahlgba01.shtml">Babe Dahlgren</a>  (1935-1946)</p>**strong text**
```

and here is my script:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

url = "http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/d/"
content = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = bs(content, "html.parser")

for player_url in soup.b.find_all(limit=None):
        for player_link in re.findall('/players/', player_url['href']):
                  print ('http://www.baseball-reference.com' + player_url['href'])
```

The other part is that there are other div id's that have similar lists that I don't care about. I want to grab the URLs from only this div class, that have a `<b>` tag. The `<b>` tag symbolizes that they are active players and that is what I am trying to capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BeautifulSoup to do the "selection" work and drill down to your data:

```
url = "http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/d/"
content = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = bs(content, "html.parser")

bolds = soup.find_all('b')
for bold in bolds:
    player_link = bold.find('a')
    if player_link:
        relative_path = player_link['href']
        print('http://www.baseball-reference.com' + relative_path)
```

Now, if only want the one `div` with `id=div_players_` you could add an additional filter:

```
url = "http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/d/"
content = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = bs(content, "html.parser")

div_players = soup.find('div', {'id': 'div_players_'})
bolds = div_players.find_all('b')
for bold in bolds:
    player_link = bold.find('a')
    if player_link:
        relative_path = player_link['href']
        print('http://www.baseball-reference.com' + relative_path)
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up figuring it out shortly after I submitted the question. Been working on this all day and go figure right when I ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing

```
url = 'http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/d/'
content = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = bs(content, 'html.parser')

for player_div in soup.find_all('div', {'id':'all_players_'}):
        for player_bold in player_div('b'):
                    for player_href in player_bold('a'):
                        print ('http://www.baseball-reference.com' + player_href['href'])
```